# Connecting two DC-DC 0-200V SSRs in series

Tags: mosfet, dc, induction-motor, solid-state-relay

I want to switch a 400V DC inductive load.

I am unable to find 0-400V DC to DC switching SSR.

Can I use two DC to DC SSR of 0-200V in series to achieve the goal?

Comment: No, one will break the current before the other, leaving 400 V across the other one, making it go up in smoke. Get a 600 V one and do the job properly.

Comment: IXYS makes SSRs rated for up to around 1000 V; if you need higher than that, make your own with a PV optocoupler and a high-voltage MOSFET or two.

Comment: @winny that should be the answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: One point that has been missed so far is if you are switching an inductive load the voltage rating of the SSR has to be much higher than applied voltage due to back EMF. How much higher depends on inductance and SSR turn off time. Slower switching will reduce the issue but result in higher switch losses. RC snubbers may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind. Either simply get an SSR rated for enough voltage (as your current requirements are unknown, I can't recommend a specific one here, but you can always use the SSR to switch a transistor; see below. I recommend looking at SSRs from IXYS; they make some rated for 1000 V/1 A.), or use a configuration like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNDHfQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The SSR in this configuration only needs to be rated for 10~20-ish volts (to be on the safe side, I'd use one rated to 50 V or so); the SiC JFET drops the rest of the voltage. Any SiC JFET can be used here, or (if you can find one) a depletion-mode MOSFET rated for sufficiently high voltage.

Of course if you want isolation, the SSR still needs to be rated to an isolation voltage of at least 400 V in the appropriate isolation class.

---

Given the high cost of SiC JFETs, I would recommend just getting an adequately-rated SSR. A few potential issues and ways to get around them follow:

If your constraint is that you can't get an SSR with a high enough current rating, but you can get one with an adequate voltage rating if you relax the current requirement, you can just hook it up like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1yn2H.png)</sup>

Here, both the transistor and the SSR need to be rated for the full load voltage, but only the transistor needs to be rated for the full current. (You can do this with a MOSFET too, of course, but a BJT is more convenient in this case if you can handle the higher voltage drop.)

If instead you can't get an SSR rated for the voltage you need at all, no matter the current rating, then the solution is to make your own SSR like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ctzE.png)</sup>

The JFET can be any cheap JFET rated for at least the open-circuit voltage of the optocoupler. The JFET and 1 MΩ resistor can be omitted entirely if you use an optocoupler like the VOM1271, which has built-in fast turn-off circuitry.